# Завершить запущенный из книги сторонний процесс с удалением файла процесса

Tags: excel, vba

Здравствуйте Уважаемые программисты!
Помогите пожалуйста решить кодом vba следующую задачу: по кнопке в книге excel 2003 выполняется копирование файла приложения "form_v1.exe" (это окно с полями и кнопкой Закрыть) во временную папку, из которой этот файл сразу после копирования запускается.
Пользователь работая с книгой может завершить сам процесс "form_v1.exe" (закрыть окно) или не сделать этого.
Вопрос: Как при закрытии этой книги: 1) завершить запущенный процесс "form_v1.exe" если он еще выполняется, т.е. прервать его при необходимости принудительно, 2) удалить из временной папки файл процесса "form_v1.exe".
Примечание: файл процесса "form_v1.exe" может быть с разным именем, но имя всегда начинается с "form*".
Код ниже работает корректно только в случае, если пользователь до закрытия книги сам завершил процесс.
Спасибо за любые Ваши подсказки.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
 Dim Process As Object
 For Each Process In GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process")
  If Process.Caption Like "form*" Then
   Process.Terminate
  End If
 Next
 Kill Environ("temp") & "\" & "form*"
End Sub
```

Comment: Представляю, как будет счастлив пользователь, если при закрытии книги Excel будет убит процесс (просто для примера) FormatFactory.exe, который несколько часов до этого конвертировал видео ))

Answer (score 0):

Ну для начала - хотя бы

```
For Each Process In GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery( _
         "Select * from Win32_Process Where Caption Like 'form%'") 
    HResult = Process.Terminate  
    Select Case HResult
        Case 0
            MsgBox "Successful completion"
        CASE 2
            MsgBox "Access denied"
        CASE 3
            MsgBox "Insufficient privilege"
        CASE 8
            MsgBox "Unknown failure"
        CASE 9
            MsgBox "Path not found"
        CASE 21
            MsgBox "Invalid parameter"
        CASE Else
            MsgBox "Other error"
    End Select
Next
```

> Код ниже работает корректно только в случае, если пользователь до закрытия книги сам завершил процесс.

Так в этом случае работает только Kill... чего бы ему не работать корректно?

А что наблюдается, если пользователь НЕ завершил процесс?

1. процесс не выгружается (вряд ли)
2. процесс выгружается, но файл не удаляется (скорее всего)

**UPDATE**

> Да, процесс выгружается, но файл не удаляется из временной папки

Файл не удаляется потому, что выгрузка выполняется асинхронно. Как результат - на момент попытки Kill команда Terminate уже послана, но ещё не выполнена, а файл соответственно залочен. Решение - после первого получения процессов и отправки команд на выгрузку снова запрашивать в цикле с небольшой (100 мс) задержкой список процессов, пока он не опустеет, и лишь потом удалять файлы.

Answer (score 0):

Код ниже - для запуска приложения "form_v1.exe", срабатывает щелчком по кнопке в книге excel 2003, и не даст закрыть книгу пока не закрыто приложение, а значит процесс "form_v1.exe" отслеживать и прерывать не потребуется:

```
Dim sFileName As String, sNewFileName As String
sFileName = "\\server\form_v1.exe"
sNewFileName = Environ("temp") & "\" & "form_v1.exe"
FileCopy sFileName, sNewFileName

Dim FullPath As String
Dim wsh As Object
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean
Dim windowStyle As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
waitOnReturn = True
windowStyle = 1
FullPath = Environ("temp") & "\" & "form_v1.exe " & Chr(34) & ThisWorkbook.FullName & Chr(34)
wsh.Run FullPath, windowStyle, waitOnReturn
```

Нужно лишь при закрытии книги очистить из временной папки следы приложения:

```
Dim sFileName As String
sFileName = Environ("temp") & "\" & "form*"
If Dir(sFileName, 16) <> "" Then
  Kill sFileName
End If
```

Подскажите Ваше мнение?